# Setting variable name from sql table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a Mysql table containing 2 columns
1 column - variable name
2 сolumn - text string containing a command. (for example: "echo 123")

I am retrieving these rows from a table:

```
mapfile i <<(mysql autoclicker_metrics -u root -se "select * from variable;")
```

Further in the loop I want to assign commands of the form

```
n=$(echo 123)
m=$(df -h)
```

And so on, taking the linking variable name + its value from the table
For this, I create a loop

```
for row in "$ {i [@]}"; do
$ {row% $ '\ t' *} = $ (echo $ {row # * $ '\ t'})
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: If I create a loop  
  
```for row in "$ {i [@]}"; do```  
```n = $ (echo $ {row% $ '\ t' *})```  
```m = $ (echo $ {row # * $ '\ t'})```  
```echo $ n```  
```echo $ m```  
```done```  
  
Then it outputs values from the table  
var1  
echo 123  
var1  
echo 321

Answer (score 0):

```
mapfile i < <(mysql autoclicker_metrics -u root -se "select * from variable;")  
for row in "${i[@]}";do  
n=$(echo ${row%$'\t'*})  
m=$(echo ${row#*$'\t'})  
k=$(echo $n=\"$m\")  
eval $k  
eval '$'$n  
done
```